# How Should I create a Media Player only once and call it multiple times?

Tags: java

So I'm working on a small mobile game and when I tap on a button it should play a sound effect. I want it to play multiple instances within a small time frame, so SoundPool doesn't work in my case.
Right now, I'm using this method

```
public void playTapSound(){
        final MediaPlayer gameSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tapsound);
        gameSound.start();
    }
```

However, I do not call gameSound.release anywhere as I'm not sure where to call it. So after 40 uses, the sounds stop playing presumably due to too many MediaPlayers being created.

I tried placing

```
final MediaPlayer gameSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tapsound);
```

into onCreate(), but when I do that, gameSound becomes an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'gameSound'".

If I place it before or after onCreate(), the app just crashes as "this" is null.

When a button is tapped there's some other stuff then I run too

```
    public void tapped(View view) {
        if (!buttons[0].isAllCaps()) {
            playTapSound();
            buttons[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1fab89"));
            buttons[0].setAllCaps(true);
            score++;
            x++;
            points.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }
        else {
            buttons[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#505bda"));
            lose(score);
        }
    }
```

Hoping I can get some help on where to place a gameSound.release() or how to call gameSound when the player is created on onCreate(). thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about use [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

```
public final class MediaPlayerHolder {
    private static final MediaPlayerHolder INSTANCE = new MediaPlayerHolder();

    public static MediaPlayerHolder getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private MediaPlayerHolder() {
    }


    private MediaPlayer gameSound;

    // get with required parameters
    public MediaPlayer get(...) {
        if(mediaPlayer == null)
            gameSound = MediaPlayer.create(...);
        return gameSound;
    }

}

public void playTapSound(){
    MediaPlayerHolder.getInstance().get().start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gameSound` becomes a *local* variable in both of your attempts. First it is local to `playTapSound()`, and thus not accessible from anywhere else, second it is local to `onCreate()`, and thus not even accessible from `playTapSound()` either.
Create an object-level variable instead, outside of the methods (and thus available to all of them):

```
private MediaPlayer gameSound;

... onCreate(){
  ...
  gameSound=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.tapsound);
  ...
}

public void playTapSound(){
  gameSound.start();
}
```

(However I do not know if it will run, this suggestion focuses on the compilation+visibility problem, I do not know if `start()` can be called multiple times - perhaps yes, perhaps you can simply put a stop immediately before the start, perhaps you have to track if it is still playing, and stop it only in that case).

(Side note: `final` makes a variable non-modifiable after initialization. It is not related to sharing variables between methods, and you do not need it here.)